# How to create a function that can wait for multiple processes to exit?

Tags: vb.net, process, multiple-processes

I am creating a windows service that will write all the start time and exit time for specific process that I wanted to monitor. The problem is when I am trying to monitor the process to wait for exit, I have no idea on how to wait multiple process to exit. Below are my code for writing the start time of the process.

```
Try
    Using regkey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64).OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\MonitoringApplication\Login", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.Default)
        childrenID = regkey.GetValue("Login User").ToString
    End Using
    If childrenID.Equals("admin") Then
    Else
        Dim connection As New SqlConnection("Server=DESKTOP-FTJ3EOA\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MonitorDB;User ID = admin; Password = admin")
        Dim command As New SqlCommand("SELECT  App.ApplicationName FROM App INNER JOIN ChildrenApplication ON App.ApplicationID = ChildrenApplication.ApplicationID WHERE ChildrenID = @a", connection)
        command.Parameters.Add("@a", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = childrenID
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter(command)
        Dim table As New DataTable()
        adapter.Fill(table)

        Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\MonitoringApplication.txt", True)

            For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
                p = Process.GetProcessesByName(row.Item(0))
                Using myprocess = New Process
                    If p.Count > 0 Then
                        myprocess.StartInfo.FileName = row.Item(0)
                        myprocess.EnableRaisingEvents = True
                        sw.WriteLine(row.Item(0) + "running")

                    End If
                End Using
            Next row
        End Using

        Const SLEEP_AMOUNT As Integer = 100
        Do While Not eventHandled
            elapsedTime += SLEEP_AMOUNT
            If elapsedTime > 30000 Then
                Exit Do
            End If
            Thread.Sleep(SLEEP_AMOUNT)
        Loop
    End If
Catch ex As Exception
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\MonitoringApplication.txt", True)
        sw.WriteLine(ex)
    End Using
End Try

Private Sub myProcess_Exited(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles myProcess.Exited
    eventHandled = True
    Using sw As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "\MonitoringApplication.txt", True)
        sw.WriteLine("Exited")
    End Using
End Sub
```

Is there any ways to monitor multiple process to exit? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yep. Set `EnableRaisingEvents = true`, subscribe to the `Exited` event. When the event is raised, the `object` of the event is the Process that is about to exit. Cast the `object` to Process. Then `Close()` and `Dispose()` if not null.

Comment: @Jimi Hi jimi, i have have implemented the EnableRaisingEvents, but i not sure whether the way i code is correct or not.

Comment: You didn't subscribe to the `Exited` event. I'll make example, so it's more clear how you can proceed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're now using [Process.GetProcessesByName()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.getprocessesbyname) to retrieve an array of running processes, if any.
You can use the returned array of processes and subscribe to the [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited) event of each one to log the exit time of any of the processes in the array.

Setting [EnableRaisingEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.enableraisingevents) is necessary to raise the `Exited` event, but you also need to subscribe to event, using `AddHandler` along with the address of a method or a Lambda:

```
AddHandler [Process].Exited, AddressOf [Handler]
' or 
AddHandler [Process].Exited, Sub() [Lambda]
```

This method accepts a process name and the path to a file where to store the name of the process and its exit time when the `Exited` event is raised.

If your current loop:

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    '(...)
Next
```

You can insert a call to this method:

```
For Each row As DataRow In table.Rows
    SubscribeProcExit(row.Item(0), Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "MonitoringApplication.txt"))
Next
```

If the log file doesn't exit, it will be created and a new line is added each time one of the Processes exits, logging the `Process.ProcessName` and `Process.ExitTime`.
Note that **`row.Item(0)`** must contain the friendly name of the Process. For example, `notepad.exe` must be referenced as just `"notepad"`.

```
Private Sub SubscribeProcExit(processName As String, fileName As String)
    Dim processes As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(processName)
    If processes.Length = 0 Then Return
    For Each p As Process In processes
        p.EnableRaisingEvents = True
        AddHandler p.Exited,
            Sub()
                Using sw As StreamWriter = File.AppendText(fileName)
                    sw.WriteLine($"Process: {p?.ProcessName}, Exit Time: {p?.ExitTime}")
                    p?.Dispose()
                End Using
            End Sub
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Jimi! Now i know how to use EnableRaisingEvent. Thank you so much